# Describing an inaccurate statement

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I would like to describe a statement as failing to be accurate, but I'm struggling to articulate it in a manner which may be considered grammatically correct. I had initially written: "Not only does his statement fail in terms of accuracy", but then disregarded it and went with: "Not only does his statement fail on account of its inaccuracy", but that doesn't sound right to me either. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps we'd be able to help you better if you told us the specific 'inaccurate' statement?

Comment: I don't doubt that the statement I'm writing about is inaccurate, I'm just not sure if I am wording my sentence correctly. Are the two examples I provided wrong? is so, is do you have a better example? Thanks.

Comment: Your examples aren't wrong; I'm merely saying that providing the statement you're referring to may help us in finding a better alternative for 'inaccurate' for that context it's being used in, if such a one exists. @liston

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure if they sounded right or if I was using "in terms of" correctly. I was wanting to say that the statement failed not only to be factually correct, but also to mitigate the moral repugnancy of the statement through the use of romanticised language.

Comment: Perhaps another alternative then would be the word **specious**, meaning "lacking real merit; superficially pleasing or plausible; pleasing to the eye but deceptive"  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/specious

Comment: Excellent word, thank you. I could definitely describe the arguments as _specious_.

Comment: liston ~ glad I could help then ;) (despite not knowing the actual arguments)

Comment: I'm confused -- are you discussing an argument or a statement?  A statement (or in formal terms in logic, a "proposition") is just one part of an argument.  "The sky is blue, and pigs cannot fly, therefore I am a lobster."  Both of the statements (sky is blue, pigs can't fly) are accurate, but the argument is fallacious.  As opposed to "The sky is green, and grass is green, therefore I have a hard time seeing the horizon" - the proposition "sky is green" is inaccurate, but assuming it *were* true, the argument would be correct.

Comment: John - my mistake. I did use the word 'argument' above, but I was initially referring to a statement made by an author that I believed to be factually incorrect as well as contemptible. Just for an example, suppose someone said something along the lines of "Dog-fighting is the only sport where the handler truly loves his animal". Granted, it is a rather poor example but it demonstrates what I was getting at - that it is demonstrably false as well as deserving of disdain. Apologies for the long overdue reply, and I've long since finished what I was writing, but wanted to clarify nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would help just to simplify it a bit. To wit:

***Not only is his statement inaccurate...***

or

***His statement is not only inaccurate, it is...***